# Exibir algumas DIV com valor do input

Tags: javascript, div

Bom dia Caros,
Estou com uma duvida no estudo.
Preciso que seja exibido apenas algumas div do formulário, Ja tentei algumas métodos, sem sucesso.

Eu salvo OK, 
Eu escolho 1 das 3 opções no cadastro
Me apresenta os input que preciso, e salva.
Mas na edição como que eu faço para aparecer somente os valores correspondente ao valor do radio. so consigo apresentar todos juntos

tenteis algumas coisas como empty, ou talvez eu nao soube usar uma colocação para ele

```js
function mostra(valor) {
  if (valor == "IF") {
    document.getElementById("IF").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("CAD").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DROID").style.display = "none";


  } else if (valor == "CAD") {
    document.getElementById("IF").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("CAD").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("DROID").style.display = "none";



  } else if (valor == "DROID") {
    document.getElementById("IF").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("CAD").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DROID").style.display = "block";

  }



}

function mostra(theId) {
  var theArray = new Array('IF', 'CAD', 'DROID');
  w = document.getElementById(theId)
  if (w.style.display == "block") {
    w.style.display = 'none';
  } else {



    for (i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
      if (theArray[i] == theId) {
        w.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        document.getElementById(theArray[i]).style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```css
#IF,
#CAD,
#DROID {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body" class="row">
  <label><b>Selecione</b></label>&nbsp;
  <label class="radio-inline">
 <input onclick="mostra('IF')" type="radio" name="tipo" value="IF" >  IF&nbsp; </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
 <input onclick="mostra('CAD')" type="radio" name="tipo" value="CAD" > CAD&nbsp; </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
 <input onclick="mostra('DROID')" type="radio" name="tipo" value="DROID"> DROID &nbsp; </label>
  <hr>
</div>
<form method="post" action="#" id="pdvcad">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="IF">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2"><label>ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="idif" id="idif" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3"><label>Tipo:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="modelo" name="modelo">
       <option id="modelo" value="POS">POS</option>
       <option id="modelo" value="MP">MP</option>
      </select>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-md-3"><label>Pedido:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pedido2" id="pedido2" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="CAD">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4"><label>Numero Serie:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nserie" id="nserie" maxlength="11" data-mask="000000000-00" class="form-control showcase sweet" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4"><label>Versao:</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="versao" id="versao" value="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="DROID">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-md-3"><label>Usa Cadastro<label>
      <br>
      <input id="cad" type="radio" value="NAO" name="cad" class="radio-template">
      <label for="cad">SIM</label>
            <input id="cad" type="radio" checked="" value="SIM" name="cad" class="radio-template">
            <label for="cad">NÃO</label>
          </div>
        <div class="col-md-5"><label>Licença:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lic" id="lic" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><label>Expira:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vencto" id="vencto" readonly />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

PS: ao identificar o valor do select mostrar so os valores que foi preenchido, sem precisar de um select
Como no Exemplo

Tentei com algumas explicações mas piorou as coisas

Agradeço ajuda

Comment: Na hora de trazer os dados do banco de dados tu precisa informar para a página quais são as divs que contêm dados e que precisarão ficar com display block.

ex simples:
No formulário de cadastro todas as divs estão display none, mas se no cadastro alguma delas tiver sido marcado o input, tu adiciona uma classe.

<div class="invisivel">
conteúdo 1 [foi marcado algo no cadastro]
</div>

<div class="invisivel">
conteúdo 2
</div>

<div class="invisivel">
conteúdo 3
</div>

---------------------
Trazendo dados na Edição
SE HÁ DADOS, insira uma class="visivel"
e controla no CSS

Answer (score 2):

Você carregou o JQuery e tá usando JavaScript puro, por quê?

Você poderia usar o JQuery e fazer algo do tipo:

```
<div id="nome">
    <input type="text" name="nome"  placeholder="Nome">
</div>
<div id="telefone">
    <input type="phone" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone">
</div>
<!-- Botoes -->
<button value="nome">Mostrar somente nome</button>
<br>
<button value="telefone">Mostrar somente telefone</button>
<br>
<button value="all">Mostrar todos</button>
```

JQuery

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).val() === 'nome'){
        $('#telefone').hide();
        $('#nome').show();
    } else if($(this).val() == 'telefone'){
        $('#telefone').show();
        $('#nome').hide();
    } else {
        $('#telefone, #nome').show();
    }
});
```

> A função .hide() do JQuery esconde um elemento; a função .show() mostra o elemento.

Entendeu? Não?! Eu explico.

Suponha que você tenha uma lista e que nessa lista tenha um botão para deletar e outro para editar. Quando você clicar em deletar, use o JavaScript/JQuery para pegar o valor do botão indicando uma ação, então mostrar um modal perguntando se o usuário tem certeza que deseja deletar o registro da lista.

Da mesma forma, se você clicar em editar, usa o JavaScript/JQuery para pegar o valor do botão de edição e levar o usuário para o formulário com os campos que podem ser editados.

[**JSFiddle do exemplo**](https://jsfiddle.net/urxydoo9/1/)